# Can oracle instant client be installed in an Azure Web App

Tags: php, oracle, azure

We've installed oracle instant client into an Azure virtual machine and all is running ok.  Our Oracle database is external to Azure.

However running a VM seems to be an overkill for our application and we are wondering whether we can connect from our PHP based web application to our oracle instance from an Azure Web App instead.

Is this possible and if so how?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we cannot install oracle instant client on Azure Web Apps. So we can leverage Azure VM to install oracle instant client.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Azure Web Apps- PHP with Oracle using OCI8 drivers, take a look at this reference: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/02/23/access-oracle-databases-from-azure-web-apps-using-oci8-drivers-with-php/

Comment: I ended with trying with so many options but no luck. Found this link, as per the above link it is for windows, do we have anything for Linux and I am trying to connect Oracle from azure web app PHP8.